Rotate edges in tikz
this is my code for a directed graph. I use the rotate function and now the edges are in a muddle.
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,line width=.7pt]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
column sep={1.5cm,between origins},
row sep={2.2cm,between origins},
nodes={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm,rotate=-90,transform shape}]
{
    &   |(1)| 1 &  \\
    &  |(2)| 2,3 & \\
    &  |(3)| 2,s & \\
    &  |(s)| s &\\};
\draw (1) to[bend left] (2);
\draw (1) to[bend right] (2);
\draw (2) to[out=-140, in=140] (3);
\draw (2) to[out=-110, in=110] (3);
\draw (2) to[out=-75, in=75] (3);
\draw (2) to[out=-45, in=45] (3);
\draw (3)--(s);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{turn}


I have tried many numbers in \draw (2) to[out=-45, in=45]. But it doesn't work.
It should look like this, but with rotated notes. This is without rotate=-90 in the nodes declaration.

I think I have to used to rotate the "labels", but how?

Can you complete your code so we can compile it as is? Why are you using turn exactly?

Simply use the matrix to align on a row and not a column.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,line width=.7pt]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
column sep={2.2cm,between origins},
nodes={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm,,transform shape}]
{
    &   |(1)| 1 
    &  |(2)| 2,3 
    &  |(3)| 2,s 
    &  |(s)| s &\\};
\draw (1) to[bend left] (2);
\draw (1) to[bend right] (2);
\draw (2) to[bend left=-20] (3);
\draw (2) to[bend left=-50] (3);
\draw (2) to[bend left=20] (3);
\draw (2) to[bend left=50] (3);
\draw (3)--(s);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Why not just draw it with the correct orientation in the first place? Here are four ways of doing so, but there are many more. The four here represent two strategies and two approaches to syntax.

Use a 1x4 matrix rather than a 4x1 matrix. Keep the syntax verbose for readability.
The same but use more compact syntax by utilising loops to join the nodes.
Use chains rather than a matrix. Use fairly verbose syntax for readability and utilise the scopes library to reduce clutter.
The same but use loops for greater compactness.

You could also code this as a graph or a tree. The final example below uses forest just for fun. (There is really not much to be said for using forest here.)
Note that which version to use is largely a matter of taste. There is virtually no difference between the results.





\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720017/ addaswyd o gwestiwn VD3: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/720012/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta,chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
% chains & scopes (verbose)
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,line width=.7pt]
  { [start chain=C,every node/.style={circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,on chain,anchor=center},node distance=1.7cm]
    \node {$1$};
    \node {$2,3$};
    \node {$2,s$};
    \node [join] {$s$};
  }
  \draw (C-1) to[bend left] (C-2);
  \draw (C-1) to[bend right] (C-2);
  \draw (C-2) to[bend left=40] (C-3);
  \draw (C-2) to[bend left=20] (C-3);
  \draw (C-2) to[bend right=20] (C-3);
  \draw (C-2) to[bend right=40] (C-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
% chains & scopes (compactish)
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,line width=.7pt]
  { [start chain=C,every node/.style={circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,on chain,anchor=center},node distance=1.7cm]
    \node {$1$};
    \node {$2,3$};
    \node {$2,s$};
    \node [join] {$s$};
  }
  \foreach \i/\j [evaluate=\i as \k using {int(\i+1)}] in
  {1/30,2/20,2/40}  \draw (C-\i) edge [bend right=\j] (C-\k) to [bend left=\j] (C-\k) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
% matrix (verbose)
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,line width=.7pt]
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,
  column sep={2.2cm,between origins},
  nodes={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm}]
  { |(1)| 1 &  |(2)| 2,3 &   |(3)| 2,s &  |(s)| s \\};
  \draw (1) to[bend left] (2);
  \draw (1) to[bend right] (2);
  \draw (2) to[bend left=40] (3);
  \draw (2) to[bend left=20] (3);
  \draw (2) to[bend right=20] (3);
  \draw (2) to[bend right=40] (3);
  \draw (3)--(s);
\end{tikzpicture}
% matrix (compactish)
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,line width=.7pt]
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
  column sep={2.2cm,between origins},
  nodes={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm}]
  { 1 &  2,3 &   2,s &  |(s)| s \\};
  \foreach \i/\j [evaluate=\i as \k using {int(\i+1)}] in
  {1/30,2/20,2/40}  \draw (m-1-\i) edge [bend right=\j] (m-1-\k) to [bend left=\j] (m-1-\k) ; 
  \draw (m-1-3)--(s);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm,
    grow'=0,
    math content,
    l sep'=1.2cm,
    line width=.7pt,
  },
  where n children=0{edge+={-Stealth,line width=.7pt}}{no edge},
  [1 [{2,3} [{2,s} [s] ] ] ]
  \begin{scope}[line width=.7pt,-Stealth]
    \foreach \i/\j [evaluate=\j as \k using {int(180-\j)}] in {r/30,r1/20,r1/40} \draw (!\i) edge [bend right=\j] (!\i1.-\k) to [bend left=\j] (!\i1.\k) ;
  \end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}


Here is a tikz-cd solution:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrows=-Stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes=draw, circle, font=\small, minimum size=1cm}, column sep={2.2cm,between origins}]
1\arrow[r, bend left]\arrow[r, bend right] 
    & 2,3\arrow[r, bend left=20]\arrow[r, bend right=20]\arrow[r, bend left=40]\arrow[r, bend right=40]
    & 2,s\arrow[r] 
    & s
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}

